# Did any scanners marketed as general purpose implement SCSI device type 06h (SGC)?

Tags: scsi

SCSI-connected (flatbed) scanners existed a lot in the 90s and early 2000. Usually, they did need a vendor or vendor-specific (TWAIN, sane...) device driver to work, and IIRC usually implemented the 03h (PROCESSOR) device type.

Why was the device type and command set from the SCSI specification meant for such devices not used in many popular devices, and did any mass market scanners implement it at all?

Comment: As far as I can tell there was no separate SGC command set document. There was a scanner command set defined in SCSI-2 but it was never made into own document for SCSI-3 like most of the other device types defined in SCSI-2. SPC-3 made device type 06h obsolete, so I suspect it was never used.

Answer (score 1):

The HP ScanJet 5p may have done. I ran one under Linux before 2002, and it needed a different SCSI driver that was sold as part of the tummy.com XVScan package. It referred to itself as a "SCSI SG driver", so maybe?

Comment: SG is scsi generic usually...

Comment: In that case you could use a SCSI SG driver to scan a copy of your PIN number into an OS that was built on NT technology.